# jvisualvm Does not list Jboss 5.1.0GA when running as service

Tags: java

jvisualvm does not monitor the jboss when I run it as service? what changes i need to make so that jvisualvm start monitoring the java application (specifically jboss) when running as window service.
Moreover, When I run the jboss through command prompt (run.bat) jvisualvm start monitoring it.
Please suggest..

Answer (score 3):

VisualVM can automatically detect only java applications running under the same user as VisualVM. See [this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as) to find out how you can monitor java process running as Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Visual VM looks at active JVMs.  You need to give it the PID of the JVM that's running your JBOSS instance.

Make sure that you have Visual VM 1.3.2 with all the plug-ins installed.  It's a substantial upgrade from the version that ships with the JVM.

Comment: Yes, your right.  I just tried it.  The plugins-upgrade feature works much better with Visual VM 1.3.2 (downloaded separate from JDK).  Here is my startup command:  visualvm.exe --jdkhome "E:\Temp\JDK_TEMP\jdk1.6.0_25" --userdir "E:\Temp\visualvm_userdir"